# Putting ID in Get request

Tags: asp.net, http, web

I have a following url:

```
/Reports?reportId={value}
```

The problem is that not every user can see every report, but with this kind of url he can actually enter whatever ID he wants and access that report.

So my question is should I just add a server side validation to check if currently logged user has access to this report and if not return some Anauthorized response, or send this via POST so he cannot see the url and change it (if this approach is safe enough).

And generally I want to know if it is bad idea to send ID in url? Maybe it is better to use Guids for ID-s then instead of integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is should I just add a server side validation to check if currently logged user has access to this report and if not return some Anauthorized response

Yes, a thousand times this.

> or send this via POST so he cannot see the url and change it (if this approach is safe enough).

No. Never this. This is security through obscurity. POST data is not hidden in any way.

> if it is bad idea to send ID in url? Maybe it is better to use Guids for ID-s then instead of integers?

No, that does not matter at all. That also is security through obscurity. The GUIDs still show up in plaintext, so anyone with access to browser history, firewalls, or the network in general can inspect and replay the traffic containing GUIDs.

See also [Why not expose a primary key - Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218306/why-not-expose-a-primary-key).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to CodeCaster's answer:

IDs in URLs can indirectly reveal some business related information. For example from contract ID=963 your competitor may learn that you did since last month 40 new contracts (ID was e.g. 923) and earned cca 50k. This is sometimes not desired.

It's quite common though to mask ID e.g. by converting into a masked string. I usually use `openssl_encrypt` and `openssl_decrypt` respectively.

Here's example for converting ID to/from masked string:

```
public static function encryptOpenssl($textToEncrypt, $encryptionMethod = 'AES-256-CFB', $secretHash = "12#rk!", $raw = false, $password = ''){
    $length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($encryptionMethod);
    $iv = substr(md5($password), 0, $length);
    return openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, $encryptionMethod, $secretHash, $raw, $iv);
}

public static function decryptOpenssl($textToDecrypt, $encryptionMethod = 'AES-256-CFB', $secretHash = "12#rk!", $raw = false, $password = ''){
    $length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($encryptionMethod);
    $iv = substr(md5($password), 0, $length);
    return openssl_decrypt($textToDecrypt, $encryptionMethod, $secretHash, $raw, $iv);
}
```

You can of course use any other obfuscating algo, e.g. rot13, exchanging character positions, character mapping, prepending/appending irrelevant chars etc.